# If I get "top" with jquery, what does it mean?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If I use `console.log($("#object").position().top)`, i get a number, which i assume is the "top" of the "object"

however, if i do `document.getElementById("object").style.top = $("#object").position().top;`
The object moves to a different place, (or sometimes disappears)

Can someone explain to me what is going on? Namely what "top" is `$("#object").position().top` returning?

EDIT: WHOOPs, sorry, i meant to write document.getElementById("object").style.top.

EDIT2: To clarify...

lets say i have:

```
<div id=pie>...</div>

#pie
{
    position:relative;
    top:-50;
}
```

if i do....
    console.log($("#pie").position().top);
    console.log($("#pie").offset().top);

Neither of the numbers that will be printed in the console will be -50.

EDIT3: Sorry, i meant to write top:-50;

Comment: where can you find the `top` property/attribute of a DOM element?

Comment: document.getElementById("object")`.style`.top = $("#object").position().top `+ 'px'`

Comment: Guess this would [help](http://api.jquery.com/position/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`top` in :

- `javascript` - references the topmost `window` element [[doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.top)]
- `jQuery`:

  - `$.offset().top` - returns the offset of the element relative the top of the page [[doc](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)]
  - `$.position().top` - returns the offset of the element relative to the first positioned parent [[doc](http://api.jquery.com/position/)]

### Example:

```
window0
 ├...
 └iframe1
   ├...
   └iframe2
     ├...
     └div1 style=position: relative top: * left: *
       ├...
       └div2 style=position: absolute top: * left: *
         ├...
         └div3 style /*no positioning*/
           ├...
           └div4 
               > div4.top - returns window0
               > div4.parent - returns iframe2
               > $(div4).offset().top - returns the vertical distance from the top part of iframe2
               > $(div4).position().top - returns the vertical distance from the top part of div2
```

Comment: oh, that example makes a lot of sense... thanks!
At a glance, it seems like there is no easy way to use jquery's top to position the objects using the document.getElementById

Answer (score 0):

at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.top), it is explained that :

`.top` -

> "Returns a reference to the topmost window in the window hierarchy."
>
> Where the window.parent property returns the immediate parent of the current window,
>
> window.top returns the topmost window in the hierarchy of window objects.

judging by this explanation. the result of `.top` will differ based on your window heirarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Consider .offset() http://api.jquery.com/offset/

The .offset() method allows us to retrieve the current position of an element relative to the document. Contrast this with .position(), which retrieves the current position relative to the offset parent.

Answer (score 0):

- `$(el).position().top` is the top distance **to the relative parent**.
- `$(el).offset().top` is the top distance **to the absolute parent** (window).

Also, this :

```
#pie
{
    position:relative;
    top=-50; 
}
```

**It contains 2 errors**. First, CSS use only `:` to assign a value. Second issue : -50 as no unit. So it means nothing to CSS.

I guess you meant :

```
#pie
{
    position:relative;
    top:-50px; /* px or em or % or whatever you want.*/
}
```

That may be why jQuery can't retrieve a .top value to the relative parent : in this case, it should return 0 or null maybe.